# Usando stdlib en java, al usar el StdDraw me da un error

Tags: java

Mi profe de programación nos ha dado escrito un programa para hacer un círculo y dibujarlo con StdDraw, pero no consigo que me compile.
He tenido problemas porque me daba error por la version del stdlib pero ese ya lo he solucionado y ha dejado de aparecerme, para dejarme en su lugar el siguiente error:

"Circulo.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.circle(x, y, radio);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, radio);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
Circulo.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
^
symbol:   variable StdDraw
location: class Circulo
8 errors"

El código es:

"

```
public class Circulo
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double radio;
    private Color color;

    public Circulo(double x, double y, double radio, Color color)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radio = radio;
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return new String("(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + radio + ", " + color + ")");
    }

public void mover (double dx, double dy) 
  {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  }
  public void pintar () 
  {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
    StdDraw.circle(x, y, radio);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
  }  
  public void pintarRelleno () 
  {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
    StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, radio);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
  }  
  public double area () 
  {
    return Math.PI * radio * radio;
  }
  public double radio () 
  { 
    return radio;
  }   
  public Color color () 
  { 
    return color;
  }   
}"
```

Si alguien sabe por qué me aparece ese error y ayudarme, se lo agradecería :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He copiado exactamente el código que has pasado y el único error que encuentro es que probablemente no tengas la clase `StdDraw`. Al copiar el código no tenia la clase y justo me sale el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego busque la clase en cuestión la puse en el proyecto y ya me funciono (Me hice un circulo :) ). No se si es tu caso pero tiene toda la pinta de que no encuentra esa clase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el link para descargarla: [StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java)

Puedes copiar todo el texto y pegarlo en una clase `StdDraw` o bien clic derecho y ***guardar como...***

Si estas usando el fichero `stdlib.jar` comprueba que has importado bien el fichero en el CLASSPATH y que tu IDE lo reconoce bien.

Comment: Ya me funciona! Muchísimas gracias